# MS solution for distributed computing

Tags: .net, javaspaces

I've recently moved to a MS Gold partner company after spending years in the land of community solutions and Java. I'm just starting on a project that requires distributed management of objects. In Java, javaspaces/jini would be ideal. I'm wondering if there is any MS solution that would allow for a single object to be distributed across multiple servers for both load balancing and redundancy.